# SQLServer の一つを後継機に移行する上で、影響オブジェクトを調べたい

Tags: sql-server

SQLServerを幾つか有している状況で、そのうちの一つが機器老朽化から後継機への移行を予定中です。
互いのSQLServerはデータ連携を目的に相互のデータ参照・登録・更新を達成してきており、ストアド・ビュー・ジョブといった各オブジェクトの中で、移行対象のSQLServerが定義されてしまっている部分を洗い出したいと考えています。（主にリンクサーバとしての参照が濃厚）

ビューやジョブのデザインを一覧でダウンロードするようなユーティリティはありませんでしょうか？
机上で目をとおし　影響の出ているオブジェクトだけ対策を投じたいと思っています。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Serverには[システムカタログビュー](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/catalog-views-transact-sql)と呼ばれるオブジェクト情報を取得するためのビューが多数定義されています。たとえばSQLで定義されたビューやストアドプロシージャのソースは`sys.sql_modules`から

```
SELECT object_id, definition FROM sys.sql_modules
```

のように参照できます。基本的にはここからソースコードを取得し、対象サーバー名を検索すれば可能です。

またリンクサーバー使用時にはシノニムを定義することも多いかと思いますが、`[server_name]`内のオブジェクトに対するシノニムは

```
SELECT object_id, name FROM sys.synonyms WHERE base_object_name LIKE '[[]server_name].%'
```

のように抽出でき、これらの`object_id`を`sys.sql_dependencies`の`referenced_major_id`から検索するとシノニムを使用しているSQLモジュールのオブジェクトIDが分かります。

```
SELECT * FROM sys.objects
 WHERE object_id IN(
    SELECT d.object_id
      FROM sys.synonyms s
     INNER JOIN sys.sql_dependencies d
        ON s.object_id = d.referenced_major_id
     WHERE s.base_object_name LIKE '[[]server_name].%')
```

### 追記

文字列検索より直接的なカタログビューがありました。`sys.sql_expression_dependencies`には`referenced_server_name`がありますので、ここを見れば直接参照しているSQLモジュールが分かります。

```
SELECT *
  FROM sys.objects
 WHERE object_id IN (
    SELECT referencing_id
      FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies
     WHERE referenced_server_name = 'server_name')
```

Comment: ご見解をありがとうございます、助かります。
今回のようなリンク先の環境変化に都度悩まされている状況が、実は
私も含め周囲にシノニムという機能を知るものがおらずシノニムを利用していないことが要因と
今知りました。さておき．．．
SELECT object_id, definition from sys.sql_modules
こちらビュ定義とストアドの上での使用箇所を洗い出すには十分使えそうです。
DB単位に実行して出力する必要があること、
ジョブ（Transact-SQL直書き部分も洗出したい）が出て来ていない点が悩ましい　ところでしょうか

Comment: 外部のプログラムの調査に関してはSQL Server側ではどうすることもできないですねえ。実行されたSQLを記録することはできますが、調査期間中に実行されるかどうかの保証自体がないですし、ソースを直接分析した方がフィードバックしやすいです。

Comment: この度は御世話になりました、ご提案のSELECT文をDB単位に発行して対象を抽出することにしました、ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

> ビューやジョブのデザインを一覧でダウンロードするようなユーティリティはありませんでしょうか？

どういった出力を求められているかわかりませんでした。pgrhoさんが回答されているように目的のオブジェクトを検索するのも一つの手だと思います。私からは別アプローチで。

Management Studioには[スクリプトの生成](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/sql/relational-databases/scripting/generate-scripts-sql-server-management-studio)という機能があります。これはデータベース上のすべてのオブジェクトに対して再構築可能なスクリプトを生成する機能です。つまりテーブルであれば対応する`CREATE TABLE`文が得られます。
データベース全体に対するスクリプトを取得できたら、あとは当該スクリプトをエディタなどで検索してじっくりと分析できるかと思います。

Comment: いつもお世話になっております、ご見解ありがとうございます。

>データベース上のすべてのオブジェクトに対して再構築可能なスクリプトを生成する機能。

一つ一つのオブジェクト単位（ストアド・ビュ）の操作ではなく
データベース単位の実行が可能なようですね。
ジョブについてもスクリプト出力できれるのは◎ですが、一括で出せないかなぁ．．．と今考えてます。
（IntegrationServiceのパッケージ中の接続定義は一つ一つ開いて確認する他ないかなぁ）